# How to slide to another view when table's row is clicked?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sliding

I'm new in android development and I'll appreciate any help for implementing the following thing.

I have `TabHost` and in one of the tabs I want to place some-kind of table. Clicking on one of the rows will slide this table to the left and instead of it it will show the view that corresponding to the selected row and a **back** button at the top. All this should happen in the **same** tab. [Here](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/gG64hH0x0vJsHomR8-kzGLgHgkeaZ10rE8CB6CswvE4?feat=directlink) is picture of what I'm trying to do.

My questions are:

1. What element I should use for building such kind of table?
2. How to implement such slides and back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial on view transitions. - http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html

I would think this would be a great place to start. :0)

Comment: thanks, it helped. But how you would suggest to implement that table? Or maybe this shouldn't be a table?

Comment: I would use a ListView for your table, then when they tap a row on the ListView it would take them to details for the row.

Comment: ok, but how to take them to details view for the row with slide animation? If I'll use ViewFlipper, so I can't show Nth view but only the next of previous view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's a table no doubt. Read about [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). You just need a `ViewFlipper` parent inside your first tab.

Comment: you suggest to place table inside `ViewFlipper`. But `ViewFlipper` has `Next` or `Previous` methods, so how I will flip for clicking on 1st row to view1 and for clicking on 2nd row to view2 and etc?

Comment: another way is to use ViewPager http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: I couldn't understand how to connect my table to `ViewPager` so click on row will take me to the page that matches that row. Can please explain me more specifically please?